# How to add FirstOrDefault value into cshtml dropdownlist

Tags: drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

How to add FirstOrDefault value into cshtml dropdownlist?

**Controller:** Gets First Customer that has CustomerActive == false

```
   CUSTOMERLIST singleCustomer = db.CUSTOMERLIST.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CustomerActive == false);
            ViewBag.SingleCustomer= singleCustomer;
```

**CSHTML:**

```
@Html.DropDownList("SingleCustomer", String.Empty)
```

Comment: You cant. If you use the overload where you do not bind to a property, then it needs to be `IEnumerable<T>`. But what would be the point of a dropdownlist with only one value? - Just make it a readonly textbox or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i think u misunderstood the Use of FirstOrDefault. The Following Example il explain the use of FirstOrDefault

```
 var list = new List<string>() { "cus1", "Cus2", "cus3" };
      Console.WriteLine(list.FirstOrDefault());
```

**OutPut:**

```
     cus1
```

It il take First value only.

If u checked with some condition means, a collection is empty, it returns the default value for the type.so it eliminates exceptions.

So Whatever if the checked condition is true or false you il get only one Customer value ,for displaying that value dont try dropdown list .dropdown list is used to display More then one Customers.Go for Textbox or Label .

Comment: Thank you Vinoth. I misused the FirstOrDefault. :)